# How to click on elementu using selenium, behat and mink?

Tags: php, selenium, bdd, behat, mink

I'm newbie in selenium testing. I trying use selenium2, behat and mink. As a browser I use firefox (v52.0.1). I have a problem when I try to test wiki searching (example from behat docs). The problem is when I try to click on any element on page. Then the console output is:

```
And I press "searchButton"                                 # FeatureContext::pressButton()
      mouseMoveTo
      Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
      System info: host: 'dominik-Lenovo-G580', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-66-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
      Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver (WebDriver\Exception\UnknownCommand)
```

Below my configuration and some code.

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "~3.0.5",
        "behat/mink-extension": "^2.2",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "~1.2"
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
}
```

behat.yml

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://en.wikipedia.org
            default_session: selenium2
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
```

search.feature

```
Feature: Search
    In order to see a word definition
    As a website user
    I need to be able to search for a word

    Scenario: Searching for a page that does exist
        Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
        When I fill in "search" with "Behavior Driven Development"
        And I press "searchButton" # <- the problem is on this step.
        Then I should see "agile software development"
```

FeatureContext.php

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    /**
     * @Given I click the :arg1
     */
    public function iClickTheElement($selector) // I also tried to use And I click the ".searchButton" but result is the same
    {
        $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
        $element = $page->find('css', $selector);

        if (empty($element)) {
            throw new Exception("No html element found for the selector ('$selector')");
        }

        $element->click();
    }

}
```

Console output:

[image: console output]

Do you have any ideas about this problem? I'll be very thankful for any tips.

Regards!

Update: Everythink works fine when I use Chrome to test.

Comment: Are you using Safari? if you are, try using another browser, as this is a known issue: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4136

If you are not using Safari, could you still try using another browser? If you are not currently using Chrome, try Chrome. If you are currently using Chrome, get Firefox version 44 and try that (Selenium2 has issues with more recent Firefox).

Comment: I using firefox 52. I tried to use Chrome but then I have another problem with webdriver.

Comment: Finally I did it on Chrome and everythink works fine :)

Comment: Made an answer based on this success :)

Answer (score 1):

I have commented about this and the solution suceeded, so making it an answer:

**The solution was to change the browser and use Chrome.**

The message is that the mouseMoveTo command is not supported by the remote driver. I do not know why PHP uses this particular command. I do know that the drivers for some browsers fail to support it. It is a known issue with Safari.

With Firefox 52, Selenium 2 used the "marionette" driver (now known as "Gecko" or "new Firefox" driver in Selenium 3). At the time Selenium 2 was finished, the driver was somewhat immature.

It is possible that a switch to Selenium 3 would resolve the issue. But changing to Chrome is the simplest thing to try - and a thing that, in this case, has worked.

Comment: I don't think that this is solution for the issue. This is just workaround. Nothing contributing.

Comment: Can you try the latest Selenium 3 with Firefox? If that works it is the actual solution. If that does not work, I think a Selenium bug needs to be raised.